# How to copy mongo database with all it's collection using c# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am trying to copy a mongo database using copydb command using c# driver.
But it's just create the target db with no collection inside.
When i run the command directly with the mongo shell it work fine.

These is the c# code:

```
var db = mongo.GetServer().GetDatabase("admin");
var command = new CommandDocument(new BsonElement("copydb", 1),
                                  new BsonElement("fromdb", "db1"),
                                  new BsonElement("todb", "db2")
                                 );
var result = db.RunCommand(command);
```

Its not copy the collections of db1.

These is the command i run into mongo shell and work fine:

```
db.runCommand({copydb:1, fromdb:"db1", todb:"db2"})
```

**What am i missing?**

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
var result = db.RunCommand(
            new CommandDocument(new BsonElement("copydb", 1),
                new BsonElement("fromhost", "localhost"),
                new BsonElement("fromdb", "sourcedb"),
                new BsonElement("todb", "targetdb")));
```

Comment: But it should. It is working fine in here. Getting any exception? Are you using try catch block for throwing exception?

Answer (score 0):

Next code works. It's C# MongoDB.Driver 2.0

```
var database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("admin");
var command = @"{ copydb: 1, fromhost: 'localhost', fromdb: 'from', todb: 'toDbName'}";
await database.RunCommandAsync<BsonDocument>(BsonDocument.Parse(command));
```